# BI connector from MongoDB to MySQL

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mysql-connector, bi-tool

Can anyone suggest a reliable BI connector to MongoDB either paid or free? I have already evaluated BI connector provided by Mongo in their Enterprise edition but we are using Mongo community version. I already have a BI tool. I just want the connector from MongoDB to MySQL! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

same need, to use with dataiku, datascience platform.

didn't find any free connector so far, and enterprise server licenses are not easily affordable to say the least.

so far I've been exporting Mongo to CSV then importing it in dataiku. It's not in real time, but it's good enough to do any analysis. If you need you could maybe export data every week/month/etc.

To give you an idea of the prices:

- datascience tool provides its own MongoDB connector but you need enterprise edition (waiting for pricing)
- mongodb enterprise costs 10k per server
- just contacted https://www.progress.com/odbc/mongodb
  server license £3.5k
  workstation license £150.00

Answer (score 1):

you can try **Mongo BI Connector**,for this https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/installation/，we use it in development environment but it seem to didn't work without --ssl